# How to manage burst of AWS Cloud Watch events triggering an AWS Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, system-design

I have a service which generates a burst of Cloud Watch Events once every hour. These Cloud Watch events (which could be in thousands) each will trigger an AWS Lambda function and ultimately number of concurrent lambdas running can cross the maximum limit. How can I modify my system such that these cloud watch events will be handled gracefully by Lambda functions or if possible somehow I can distribute all these cloud watch events over the rest period of the first service.

P.S. I do not want to modify the limit on concurrent running lambdas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you thought about adding these events to SQS instead of consuming Lambda directly and then configure the SQS to call the Lambda function?

This is how you can trigger a Lambda function by SQS queue

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-configure-lambda-function-trigger.html

and you can define the delay in queue consumption by using this article

https://cloudaffaire.com/how-to-configure-delay-queue-in-sqs/

Comment: The idea looks promising, but SQS cannot "call the Lambda". It's done via triggers - the same mechanism OP is already using, but with a different source. Therefore, every time an event is posted to SQS, a Lambda will be invoke to handle it. Soon you realize is suffers from the same problem - you cannot avoid the burst or delay the execution. You'd have to schedule the Lambda to run periodically to consume the queue. But that _could_ be terrible if you're only producing events during 1h of the day.

Comment: Of course, you can https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg//with-sqs.html

Comment: Yes I have thought of that . But SQS will also be populated at same rate as the cloud watch events are produced. I read that for SQS if lambda discards a request SQS re queue the message and retry will happen, how many times ? depends on configuration but that does not seems to be a good architecture and potential bug mine.

Comment: @AWS PS: clearly, you did not read what I wrote or you misunderstood the AWS documentation.

Comment: "Tutorial: Configuring Messages Arriving in an Amazon SQS Queue to Trigger an AWS Lambda Function
" !!!  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-configure-lambda-function-trigger.html

Comment: @arundhyani: The best you can do without an EC2/Fargate is put events on SQS and batch process them via Lambda - In other words, consume multiple SQS messages in a single Lambda execution. Messages may be re-queued mostly because you have a "period" to handle them after you "dequeue" them. You can configure it though.

Comment: @AWS PS: I'm not saying SQS cannot _trigger_ a Lambda. I'm saying it's not SQS that _calls_ it. There's a difference between the terms in italic. If you read my first comment, it says "SQS cannot "call the Lambda". It's done via triggers".

Comment: It's the same!, I do have 4 aws certifications Professional and Specialty ones and I know what do they mean http://marwan.info

Answer (score 0):

As prior stated you could use SQS, but I too would advise against this because you would still have the same concurrency issue (more [here](https://medium.com/@zaccharles/lambda-concurrency-limits-and-sqs-triggers-dont-mix-well-sometimes-eb23d90122e0)).

Depending on how quickly you require your processing, it may be a good idea to have lambda "poll" an SQS every couple of minutes, then send the batch of messages to a lambda to process via SNS (rather than have lambda trigger off of SQS PutMessage API Calls).